# Is there any better way to call apis parallel in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I am calling four APIs using Callable interface of java.util.concurrent with Java8. I want to do multiple rest calls, combine the results and return a JSON. I am getting the desired result, but need to know if they're any better or clean way to do this. 
Below is my code. I wanted to know which part is executed parallel and which is sequential?

```
Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>> callable1 = new Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Map<String, Object>> call() throws Exception
            {  
                return aClient.get();
            }
        };

        Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>> callable2 = new Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Map<String, Object>> call() throws Exception
            {
                return bClient.get();
            }
        };

        Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>> callable3 = new Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Map<String, Object>> call() throws Exception
            {
                return cClient.get();
            }
        };

        Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>> callable4 = new Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Map<String, Object>> call() throws Exception
            {
                return dClient.get()
            }
        };

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
        Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> future1 = executor.submit(callable1);
        Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> future2 = executor.submit(callable2);
        Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> future3 = executor.submit(callable3);
        Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> future4 = executor.submit(callable4);



        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> lists = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            putResult(future1, lists);
            putResult(future2, lists);
            putResult(future3, lists);
            putResult(future4, lists);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return metrics;
    }

    private void putResult(Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> future, Map<String, Map<String, Object>> ans) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        if(future.get() != null && future.get().size() > 0) {
            for (Map<String, Object> maps : future.get()) {
                if (maps != null && maps.containsKey("abcd")) {
                    String abcd = maps.get("abcd").toString();
                    if(!ans.containsKey(abcd))
                        ans.put(maps.get("abcd").toString(), maps);
                    else {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: maps.entrySet()) {
                            ans.get(abcd).put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
{ 
   {
    "abcd": 1,
    "cde": 2
   },
   { 
    "abcd": 2,
     "cde": 3
   }
}
```

is changed to

```
{
   "1" : {
    "abcd": 1,
    "cde": 2
   },
   "2":{ 
    "abcd": 2,
     "cde": 3
   }

}
```

in the parse function. Please, Would it be better to do it in RxJava? Also tell me how can we implement the above code in CompletableFutures?

Comment: Rxjava or reactor if you want more simplicity

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8+, you can use lambdas to significantly shorten the code.

This:

```
Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>> callable3 = new Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>>()
{
    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> call() throws Exception
    {
        return cClient.get();
    }
};
Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> future3 = executor.submit(callable3);
```

Can be shortened to this:

```
Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> future3 = executor.submit(cClient::get);
```

> I wanted to know which part is executed parallel and which is sequential?

The preparation of the callables is sequential.
The execution each of them is performed by the executor in parallel.
The parsing code however is sequential again although you haven't shown it to us, so I can't be sure. You could parallelize it too by using `future3.thenAccept(/*call to parsing method*/)` or a similar function so that the thread that executed the API call will parse the response once it's done. It should slightly improve performance over an implementation in which the worker threads just return the results, which are then parsed by a single thread.

Comment: Hey @Malt, I have added the parsing function, I do not think we can call thenAccept on the future. Please, also tell me how can we implement the above code in Completablefuture
?

Comment: @amazing_milkha The current parsing code is hard to parallelize since you're passing the same `list` every time. Anyway, I think that simplifying or parallelizing the parsing code should be a separate question from the current one which is about the simplification of the API calls.